# pagination in category template for wordpress not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

Halo Eveyone, now im doing custom wordpress task for make pagination on custome category template page without plugin. im doing this on XAMPP.. i tried so many code but the pagination doesn't work

here is my code.

for index.php, i made display all list categories with link

```
<?php
  $categories = get_categories();
   foreach($categories as $category) {
      $category_link = get_category_link($category->cat_ID);
      echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $category_link ) . '"><li>' . $category->name . '</li></a>';
   }
   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

and the list display like this

```
http://localhost/mywptask/category/category_2/
```

in category.php file

```
<?php
$currCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_name = $currCat->name;
$cat_id   = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=2&post_type=post&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$cat_id);

if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>            
        <div class="title_name"> <?php the_title(); ?> </div>
        <div class="column_content"> <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?> </div> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="pageNav04c"> 
            <?php category_pagination();?>
        </div>
<?php else : ?>
    Category not found
<?php endif;
    wp_reset_query();?>
```

i made custom setting for display pagination in functions.php

```
<?php
function category_pagination() {
   global $wp_query;
   $big = 999999999;
   $paged = paginate_links(array(
       'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
       'format' => '?paged=%#%',
       'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
       'prev_next'          => true,
       'prev_text'          => __('Previous'),
       'next_text'          => __('Next'),
       'type'               => 'list',
       'add_fragment'       => '',
       'before_page_number' => '',
       'after_page_number'  => '',
       'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
   ));

   $arr = array(
   '<li>' => '<li class="other">', 
   "'" => '"'
   );
   echo strtr($paged, $arr);
}
```

went press the next button the link go to this link

```
http://localhost/mywptask/category/category_2/page/2/
```

and it is not working... the error display "page not found".. i don't know. where is my mistake. please help me

Comment: do somebody know about this?

Answer (score 0):

This code will go in your **functions.php**.

First we check if this is the main loop and not your admin area. **pre_get_posts** can affect admin.

Then, if this is a category, we modify the **$query**.

And then return the **$query**.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse5477_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse5477_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || $query->is_admin() )
        return false; 

    if ( $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'video' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
    return $query;
}

?>
```